# Error connecting to Sharepoint site from Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Since a few days back I started receiving the below error when I try to connect to Sharepoint site.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

As per the documentation below I tried making the registry changes below and ran below Powershell command, restarted the server but still receiving the same error. Has anything changed recently?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/authentication-errors-tls12-support

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#configure-for-strong-cryptography

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
      "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
      "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
      "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
      "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

Enable-TlsCipherSuite -Name "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line of code before connecting to SharePoint Site:

PowerShell

> [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
> [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;

.NET

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

This should work for you.

Update:
Added PowerShell equivalent code.

Comment: Mine is powershell script. what should be the correct syntax?

Comment: Tried [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12  but same error

Comment: See if you are adding at the top of the script and you have not closed the session after running this as mentioned in article: https://sharepointviews.com/the-underlying-connection-was-closed/

Comment: As per this   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client  ,  NET Framework 4.6.2 and later supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.   I already have 4.7 installed. So why do I need to add this line again?

Comment: And wondering whay it was working till now and not from a week or so.